# C# windows phone 7 in a Database: Each user to have specific data tables?

Tags: c#, database, linq, windows-phone-7

I'm at my first windows phone 7 app that uses databases. I've created a database that has 4 Tables:

```
namespace database
{
public class AccountDataContext : DataContext
{
    public AccountDataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
    public Table<Account> Accounts
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<Account>();
        }
    }

    public Table<user> users
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<user>();
        }
    }

    public Table<link> links
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<link>();
        }
    }
    public Table<player> players
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<player>();
        }
    }
}
}
```

and i made a login page where you can login or register a new user...

The 'problem' is that every user that registers and logs in can see the same data .

I want to know how to split(or something) the database so that the tables: Account, link and player would be specific to every user that is added in the "user" table. Or should i make a new database for every new user that registers?

Comment: What does your database look like? Do the tables have any sort of relationships?

Comment: none.
I thought i can just add a 'user ID' field in every table(accounts, links, players).
When logging-in, saving the userID(corresponding to the user that logged in) in the database and when adding a new account, link or player information just adding the 'user ID' corresponding to the current session too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a 'user ID' field in every table class(account.cs links.cs player.cs). When logging-in, saving the userID(corresponding to the user that logged in) in the database and when adding a new account, link or player information just adding the 'user ID' corresponding to the current session too